# Types of Softwares

Tags: operating-system, software-design

Final year paper  I faced such questions related to software engineering. One of them was `"Identify three types of software applications with suitable examples."`.

Actually I cant understand and how to answer them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
Examples
System Software : System Servers
Application Software :Microsoft Office
Engineering/Scientific Software : Mat lab
Embedded Software : MP 3 Players
Product Line Software : Used in Car Companies
Web Applications : Google
Artificial Intelligence Software : AlphaGo
```